# Java: Painting to windows but not mac

Tags: java, windows, macos, swing, paint

I have designed a basic pong game that works perfectly fine on windows, however it will compile and run on Mac OS X but it will not draw anything.

Code for the JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
public class Interface extends JFrame {

/**
 * Creates a reference to a new Interface object. Sets all the parameters of the window
 */
public Interface() {
    setTitle("Pong");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBounds(600, 250, 506, 500); //setBounds(x, y, width, height)
    setResizable(false);
    setVisible(true);
}

/**
 * The main method that the program is run from.
 * @param args Command line arguments that are ignored by this method
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface window = new Interface();
    Display d = new Display();

    window.getContentPane().add(d);
    window.addKeyListener(d); //allows the user to do a certain function from the object "d", if a specified key is pressed
    d.run(); 
}
```

And basic code for the JPanel:

```
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    //set the background
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 500, 500);

    //draws the net
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    int yCoord = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i ++) {
        g.fillRect(248, yCoord, 4, 15);
        yCoord += 30;
    }

    //draws the players paddles
    player1.draw(g);        
    player2.draw(g);

    //draws the ball
    ball.draw(g);

    //draws the player scores
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString(player1.getScore()+"            "+player2.getScore(), 224, 10);
}

//Constructor
public Display() {
    player1 = new Player(10, 10, 1);
    player2 = new Player(480, 10, 2);
    ball = new Ball();
}

@Override
public void run() {
    boolean running = true;
    long startloop;
    long wait;
    long elapsed = 0;

    System.out.println("Game is running");

    while (running) {
        startloop = System.nanoTime(); //starts the timer

        //if (elapsed >= 1) {

            //checks to see if there is a winner and updates the location and drawing of the ball
            int win = ball.update();

            //checks to see if the ball has collided with anyone
            if (ball.checkPlayerCollision(player1)) {
                ball.collideWithPlayer(player1);
            } else if (ball.checkPlayerCollision(player2)) {
                ball.collideWithPlayer(player2);
            }

            if (win == 1) {
                player1.scored();
                ball.reset();
            } else if (win == 2) {
                player2.scored();
                ball.reset();
            }

            repaint(); //redraws the entire panel
            elapsed = 0;
        //}

        elapsed += (System.nanoTime() - startloop);

        wait = targetTime - elapsed / 1000000;

        if(wait < 0) {
            wait = 5;
        }

        //makes the while loop pause 
        try {
            Thread.sleep(wait);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I tried putting print statement everywhere, and everything works fine, it just wont access the paint method. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're asking "why won't my code run correctly", but are posting non-compilable and non-runnable code snippets. To get better help, consider instead creating and posting a [minimal example program](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program, the smallest possible, that compiles and runs for us, without need of images, and that shows us your problem. This program should be extremely simple, but again, should demo the problem. Please check out the link.

Answer (score 3):

Your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Interface window = new Interface();
    Display d = new Display();

    window.getContentPane().add(d);
    window.addKeyListener(d); 
    d.run();  // ***************** here ***************
}
```

You appear to be calling the `run()` method of a Thread or runnable (you don't show the class heading, so it's impossible to know) which guarantees that no background thread will be made. Instead call the `start()` method of the Thread that holds your Runnable.

so perhaps you will want to change

```
d.run();
```

to:

```
new Thread(d).start();
```

But again, in the future, when asking "why won't my code run correctly", consider creating and posting a [minimal example program](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), a small program, the smallest possible, that compiles and runs for us, without need of images, and that shows us your problem.

As an aside:

- In general, don't override a JPanel's `paint(...)` method but rather its `paintComponent(...)` method.
- And call the super's method inside of your override.
- Usually it's better to use Key Bindings and not KeyListeners with Swing programs.

Comment: And [Initial Threads](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html)